# Automation Error Creating Shortcut

Tags: excel, vba

I have created the following, and it is causing me trouble at the moment!

I can't see any reason why this wouldn't work, it works for a generic URL - just not if I try and make a URL open in a specific browser

```
Function Quote(inputText As String) As String
  Quote = Chr(34) & inputText & Chr(34)
End Function

Sub CreateShortCut()
 Dim oWSH As Object
 Dim oShortcut As Object
 Dim sPathDeskTop As String
 Dim tPath As String


 tPath = Quote("C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Application Virtualization Client\sfttray.exe") & " /exe ff.exe " & Quote("Mozilla Firefox 38.3.0.0.1.V04") & " https://dwp.reach-interactive.com/account/login/"



Set oWSH = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
 sPathDeskTop = oWSH.SpecialFolders("Desktop")

Set oShortcut = oWSH.CreateShortCut(sPathDeskTop & "\" & _
 "Example Shortcut" & ".url")
 With oShortcut
 .TargetPath = tPath
 .Save
 End With
 Set oWSH = Nothing
 MsgBox "Shortcut Created!"
 ActiveWorkbook.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: When creating a shortcut that points to an executable file, the extension will be .lnk and not .url.